# why does date() not work after loading lubridate package?

Tags: r, date, lubridate

Every day, I use date() function in R to create a new working folder named with today's date. But, it does not work as soon as I load lubridate package. date() works again when I remove the package. What does lubridate do so 'date' function work differently? While loading the lubridate package, the message is:

```
    Attaching package: ‘lubridate’. The following object is masked from 
    ‘package:base’: date.
```

What should be the value of x in date(x) to get today's date and time?

```
date() #works well
library(lubridate) 
date() #does not work now. Error Msg: Error in as.POSIXlt(x, tz = tz(x)) : 
    #argument "x" is missing, with no default
detach("package:lubridate", unload=TRUE)
date() #now it works again without "x"
```

Comment: Use `base::date()`  it is a masking issue when the functions have the same name in different packages.  One option is to use `::`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `date()` gets masked out by the function that bears the same name `lubridate::date()`

A workaround is to use `base::date()`

Answer (score 2):

Basically lubridate contains a function named "date" so when you load the lubridate package you are using `date()` function from that package and not from the base package.

If you want to use a specific function from lubridate package just type `lubridate::"the name of the function goes here"` without loading lubridate package.